# Continual integration, delivery and deployment of a Springboot Application

Tags: docker, spring-boot, jenkins, kubernetes, sonarqube

I have an assignment to continually integrate, deliver and deploy a Springboot application with Angular using: Gitlab CI, Docker, Kubernetes, Jenkins and SonarQube. My assignment name was as the question is titled with using the technologies described. Any help would be much appreciated. I've already searched the web and learned about these technologies. My question is: How and where to start, which steps should i define so I could complete my assignment? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide the references you have used to do your learning/research. What is your high level plan? Do you have a flow diagram?

Comment: I've read about continuous integration on medium.com. Read the documentation of each technology, and watched some video tutorials. My plan is to make a CRUD application and deploy it on a private server in a docker container. Also i would like to split my app to microservices with Kubernetes. All this would have to work with continual integration using jenkins and gitlab CI

Comment: Where on medium.com?

Comment: https://medium.com/@flow.ci/what-is-continuous-integration-27666c51f477

Comment: Ok, this is not a technical article. Question, why do you want to use 2 CI services? GitLab CI and Jenkins. Surely there should be only one. Here is a better [tutorial](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a repo in gitlab with branches test and prod
- Setup docker image build pipeline ( for both the branches ) that will build/test the code and package it in docker image using multi state build ( gitlab CI)
- Configure a webhook that triggers a deployment to test environment ( either in jenkins or gitlabci)
- Configure a downstream job that can be run manally to deploy to production ( in jenkins or gitlab CI)
- In both the deploymenet steps above you will need the declatrivate deployment manifests for kubernetes

The above are just basics , there are many other tools that can be used for kubernetes deployments.

The usual approch is to commit code to testing/dev and then build/test the docker image and triger test deployment as soon as the image is arrived in registry. if everything goes well , then you just port the change to prod branch that will trigger the pipeline again for building/testing the prod image followed by deployment.